# Adding Space after two title images not working, how would I fix it?

Tags: spacing, graphics, titles, report

I am a new LaTeX user and created a simple document. Now, I want to insert some extra space after my title images. How would I do that? I tried \medskip but it is not working. Also, how would I insert space in between my images- can I control the amount of space somehow?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[cc]{titlepic}

\title{
\leavevmode\smash{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Logo.PNG}
\includegraphics [width=4cm]{Logo.PNG} 
}
\medskip
Internship Report 
}
\author{%
FirstName LastName
}
\date{\today}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The titling package provides tools for a fully customisable  `\maketitle` command:

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titling}

\setlength{\droptitle}{-20ex}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehooka}{\centering\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Logo.PNG}
\quad\includegraphics [width=4cm]{Logo.PNG}\vskip 6ex}

\title{Internship Report}
\author{%
FirstName LastName
}
\date{\today}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I want to anticipate my best wishes and sincere congratulations on your next reputation of 200k.

Comment: Grazie tante, @Sebastiano. I miei auguri anche!